# An important club and two competing applicants

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

At first sight it seemed like an interview with dozens of very important looking members at the table (on one side) and only two funny looking guys on the other side. One even had a hat on his head. The conversation was little hard to hear though.

> **Member 1 (M1 )** : You are applying to join this club as a participant,
>   correct?
>
> **Applicant 1 (A1 )** : Yes, sir. We want to be part of your club.
>
> **M2** : Why?
>
> **Applicant 2 (A2 )** : We are the only two from our community not
>   included in your exclusive         club.
>
> **M1**  : Usually participants like you can only come with new members. We
>   may, just may have a member on the horizon but not certain. So we may
>   have just one opening to consider. So one of you may have a chance.
>
> (A1 and A2 look at each other, their attitude changes dramatically)
>
> **M2**  : We are an ancient club. You weren’t even born when we started
>   long time ago.
>
> **A2** : That is true for him (A1 ) but not for me. I have been ar---
>
> **A1** : (Interrupts) Besides your club has been adding new members
>   continuously. I just want to –um with –em (couldn’t hear)
>
> **M3** : We are very selective. We haven’t added a member in 30 + years.
>   What are your qualifications?
>
> **A1** : I am a valuable member of many important clubs. Like name of the
>   month club.
>
> **M3** : Is he (A2)?
>
> **A2** : No. But I belong to the prestigious Raw-- (I think I heard something like that) club
>
> **A1** :  I am import--- --rt of ----- ame  club.
>
> **A2** : So am I. More than him!
>
> **A1** :  Moms and Dads love me.
>
> **M1** : Do they like you? (looking at A2 )
>
> **A2** : No but I am part of  ---burs club. He is not!
>
> A1 : Well he is not very independent. Always needs---
>
> **A2** : Well you don’t even exist in many regions!
>
> **M3** : What? Why?
>
> **A1** : Because a –ook from my own community took my -----ful place
>
> **A2** : In other words he is doing your job for you!
>
> **A1** : Shut up. Nobody likes him—
>
> **M4** : Is that why you two are not together a lot?
>
> **M1**  : Alright alright. Any last words?
>
> **A1** : You should pick me. I may be a late comer but I am loved by
>   parents, religious minded people, healthy people.
>
> **A2** : I just want to be accepted more sir. Tired of always waiting.

*****Who are the two applicants?

What club they are applying to?

What clubs they belong (or not belong) to?

Bonus Question: Do the two have any chance of getting into this club?*****

Hint 1

> Table may be significant here

Hint 2

> One of the club they talk about is a popular Board Game

Comment: This is difficult. The member vs participant distinction probably means something... Can we expect any additional hints? :)

Comment: I have added a Hint @jafe

Comment: To bad we can't just **CTRL+F** the entire internet. :D

Comment: Are the dashes meant to be 1-for-1 replacements for missing letters? Or just signifying an unknown amount of missing letters? For instance, is there technically 2 letters missing after “Raw—“ despite the indication of mishearing what was said?

Comment: @DEEM come back please! We need your expertise and judgment on our progress.

Comment: @tjs352 I think it may not be 1-for-1 at this point; especially considering the line that follows your quoted word: *I think I heard something like that*. This seems to indicate that the word may not be in-fact, *Raw--*. DEEM, can we expect any further hints to this?

Comment: i am sorry i was on vacation in europe  no one to one.  even Raw could mean something different. i am putting a other hint.

Comment: No need for apologies, thanks very much for the hints! Hope you enjoyed Europe :) @DEEM

Comment: On the line `M3 : Is he (A2)?`, is he asking to A2 if A2 is part of this club too or is he asking A2 if A1 is really in this club?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the other answers and the hints, I think A1 and A2 are

> the letters J and Q, respectively.

and

> J is the one wearing a hat.

And the community,

> The community is the periodic table. J and Q are the only two letters who are not seen in the periodic table (Q is seen, in ununquadium, but it is only a temporary name).

Next,

> it could be that the first periodic table precedes the letter J, because J was not present in the Old English alphabet, whereas Q was.

The line about not adding members for 30+ years doesn't hold true, but I've ignored it for the moment.

> Name of the month club could be the fact that J is the most occuring first letter for months (January, June, July).

Then,

> the next club could be the most-valuable-letters-in-Scrabble club. The most valuable letters are **Q** and Z with 10 points, and then, **J** and X with 8. So, Q is more important than J.

Moms' and Dads' favourite could be the fact that

> J is a pretty common first name letter, with the Johns, and the James' and the Jennifers, whereas Q is pretty uncommon.

Now, onto the not-existing/replaced part,

> J is replaced by H in certain languages, like Spanish, Portuguese etc, and H looks like a rook. **Or** that it has been replaced by G, in certain languages, and G looks like a hook.

Then,

> Is that why you two are not together a lot?

could be pointing to the fact that

> there are only about 20 words that have J and Q in them.

Final lines could mean that

> J is loved by parents because names, religious minded people because Jesus, and healthy people because juice(?).

and

> Q wants to be accepted more, understandably, and is tired of waiting because Q = queue.

Comment: Wow this makes a lot of sense

Comment: This has to be it. I think the "30+ years without new members" clue fits as well – the latest addition would have been in 1971, when rot13[Ynjerapvhz orpnzr gur svefg ryrzrag gb pbagnva n J].

Comment: Please take my upvote, well done!! Love this answer! (+1)

Comment: just beautiful thinking Crispy Church. You got every onlue right

Comment: Wow thanks. This was a really interesting puzzle

Comment: One more thing. With Raw--- club I was thinking of Royal Club with Queens

Answer (score 1):

Taking a random swing here:

> Are the two applicants new words for scrabble?

Trying to work this out; partial answer to start. Anton has already came forth with an answer:

> The two are elements wanting to become members on the periodic table.

Where the OP has confirmed he is on the right track.

To continue from where Anton left off, and to begin breaking down the clues and clubs:

*Like -- -- the –nth club.*

> I believe this refers to the [Nth Degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nth_Degree) somehow, probably in reference to use with a polynomial or representing a very large number; as the spaces would fit: *Like I'm in the -nth club.*.

This could be wrong, but in reference to *I am an import--- --rt of -----ame club.*

> This could be *I am an important part of codename club.* but this is a long shot; fun-fact, there is actually a board game called [Codenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codenames_(board_game)).

Another possible wrong deduction could be on *Because a –ook from my own community took my -----ful place.*

> In which the missing words could be *powerful* and one of the following words: ***book***, cook, dook, gook, hook, jook, ***kook***, look, ***mook***, ***nook***, pook, ***rook***, sook, or took. I'd say the most logical being italicized and bold.

This one stumped me for a second, but in this case; *No but I am part of ---burs club. He is not!*

> There are only two seven letter words in the English language that end with *burs*; they are samburs (a type of deer) and [tamburs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_tambur) a musical instrument.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to comment on @PerpetualJ's post, but then the comment got too big so I decided to post it here.

For the community one, it could be

> a CRook from my own community took my RIGHTful place.

For the _ _ _ BURS club, it could also be

> Wilbur's club, referring possibly according to Anton's theme to either [Wilbur Atwater, the Father of Nutrition Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilbur_Olin_Atwater), or more likely [Wilbur Scoville, the Father of Burning-your-Face-Off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilbur_Scoville).

*Hypothesizing*: This means that A2 might be

> [sweet, sweet capsaicin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin), since only A2 is part of Wilbur's club. Stretching even further (I can feel it in my neck!) is it possible that A1 and A2 are applying to the hydrocarbons club? This would mean that A2 would have no chance of getting in, because capsaicin contains a nitrogen atom in apparently the spiciest of places.

Comment: Surely that club has had tons of new members in the last 30 years, no?

Comment: That was my primary reservation @jafe -- perhaps the club only contains those with no elements other than the ones described in the club name?

Comment: On point as always there @El-Guest, I'm going to tackle this some more later today and see if I can't figure it out. I always love reading your answers; not only are they loaded with knowledge, but you always have a way to throw some humor in!

Comment: Haha thanks @PerpetualJ! I've always thought learning should be fun as well as informative; I always have a great time researching for these answers! :)

Comment: That's the best way to learn of course! I've noticed you put a lot of effort into your answers. If I had the time, I would go further in depth than I do for sure!

Comment: Thanks! Always hoping to get a laugh or a smile out of the folks who read my answers :) This is a fun community to be a part of!

Answer (score 0):

> The two are elements wanting to become members on the periodic table

Comment: YOU are on the right track but look at all the other clubs and clues